# how to sort the first letter in a speciif order and the second letter in other specific order

Tags: python

I have been trying to figure out how to sort a list when first two letters are both to be arranged in a specific order.
So basically this is my code:

```
Rank = '34567890JQKA2'
Rank2 = 'DCHS'
def sort(words):
  words.sort(key=lambda x: Rank.index(x[0]))
  words.sort(key=lambda x: Rank2.index(x[1]))
return [words]
print(sort['9C', '9H', '8H', '9D'])
```

The output of this be in ascending order, so

```
>>> ['8H','9D','9C','9H']
```

line 4 sorts the first letter in order but no idea how to get the second letter sorted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set multiple params in lambda to sort.

**Ex:**

```
Rank = '34567890JQKA2'
Rank2 = 'DCHS'
def sort_func(words):
    words.sort(key=lambda x: (Rank.index(x[0]), Rank2.index(x[1])))
    return words

print(sort_func(['9C', '9H', '8H', '9D']))
```

**Output:**

```
['8H', '9D', '9C', '9H']
```

Answer (score 0):

The key for `sort` doesn't need to be a single value - if it is multiple values (in a `tuple` or `list`), they will be considered in order.

Here's a way to do it that doesn't even limit you to two characters:

```
ranks = ['34567890JQKA2', 'DCHS']

data = ['9C', '9H', '8H', '9D']
data.sort(key=lambda x: [r.index(c) for r, c in zip(ranks, x)])
print(data)
```